# SSRS PopUp Message Box

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Ive had a request from a client to make a popup box appear on the click of a databar within an SSRS report. Not had any luck with various Google Searches and just wanted to know if anybody has either got this work directly or has any suggestions for a workaround they have used?

Bit of background on the actual report itself, it simply contains a table with various stacked DataBars showing comparable data between multiple users in a system. The ability is needed to click a bar and see which User that bar relates to.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What about a Tooltip, which is native to SSRS and would accomplish a similar thing, i.e. a user would hover over the item in the chart and have some text information displayed?

Comment: That seems to do the trick, completely forgot about Tooltips. Thanks

Comment: Cool, since it was an OK workaround I've added it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite the same thing, but you can use the SSRS tooltips functionality to achieve something similar, i.e. a user will hover over a part of a chart and some contextual text information will be displayed.

[Show ToolTips on a Series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220415.aspx) has some further information.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an action to an object with a javascript popup which can show a specific URL or another report. In the action click on Fx to set an expression as follows:

I used a different script to popup a URL which contains an image url from the database:

="javascript:void(window.open('" + Fields!ImageURL.Value + "', null, 'width=800, height=500, status=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no'))"
( you can replace Fields!Image.Value with a url , this is the URL from a database field)
a
On a PC this will showup properly sized as a popup. On an iPad it will appear as a new tab.